# Is standard behavior relate to gcc version?

Tags: c, gcc

Will any of the standard C library behavior be affected by GCC version? One example I am interested in is `strncpy()` but any other examples would be interesting too.

Comment: If you keep to defined behaviour, no. However, if you venture into undefined behaviour cases, then this is a good quesion.

Comment: @Bregalad: I would tend to think that undefined behavior cases are all the same (they all yield undefined behavior, period). Think of it kind of as the **mathematical** results of `4/0` and `5/0`. They are both undefined, although the mathematical expressions that yield them look different.

Comment: Well, undefined behaviour do usually not stop the program. You *could* rely on a particular undefined behaviour by accident and still have your program working fine.

Comment: @barakmanos  *Undefinedness* is C standard's definition and a particular vendor can always *define* (which could be UB in standard C) in a particular implementation. C++11 has *defined* some *undefined*'s in C++11. There's no reason why C couldn't do that in the future.

Comment: This question would be better with a specific example/issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Will any of the standard C library behavior be affected by GCC version?*

Yes, but depends.

It's quite a broad question. There are differences in what gcc supports depending on what version of gcc you are using. gcc has many extensions which are not in standard C (hence not portable if you use those extensions). You could disable most of them with `-std=xx -pedantic-errors` flag. Assuming you have a gcc version that supports all standard C features(whatever standard you aim for), then additional differences between Standard C vs. POSIX C vs. GNU C vs. Linux specific extensions are usually documented in the manual, which you could consult to determine potential differences or extensions. As for strncpy, there's no difference in behaviour between standard C and GNU C.